# Custom renderered column sorting not working magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, renderer

I have created the custom grid with one custom column(**Products**) by renderer method which shows product name. When I tried to apply sorting it looks the custom table in which other columns exists but this field is not available in that table as it rendered, later it shows application went wrong error.

[image]

**app/code/local/Module/Name/view/adminhtml/ui_component/list.xml**

```
    <column name="products" class="Module\Name\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">pdt_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
     </column>
```

**app/code/local/Module/Name/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Products.php**

```
namespace Module\Name\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

/**
 * Class BlockActions
 */
class Products extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        CollectionFactory $product,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $product;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $pdtNames = array();           
                $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
                $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('developer',array('eq' =>$item['name']));

                foreach ($productCollection as $collection){
                    $pdtNames[] = $collection->getName();
                }
                $partnerPdts = implode(', ', $pdtNames);
                $item['partners_products'] = $partnerPdts;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: You create the grid via Grid container or UI component? Please give us these code lines of your custom column(**Product**)

Comment: Shared the code.

Comment: created the grid via UI component

Comment: @saravanavelu are you able to change the sort order! I am facing same problem

Comment: I have added tht column to custom table and it was working. May I know in which grid you facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `sortOrder` attribute. I face the same issue and adding it, fixed my sorting column issue after rendering some specific columns.

```
<column name="products" class="Module\Name\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products" sortOrder="100">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">pdt_id</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove the corresponding row in the `ui_bookmark` table. This fixed the problem for me.
2. Clean your cache after doing that.